How to convert dynamic json to csv using ChoETL
I have a dynamic json want to convert to csv.
{
  "Member": [
    {
      "Date": "2024-04-18T12:30:00Z",
      "Information": {
        "Name": "Joe",
        "Reference": "AAA0866",
        "Email": "test@test.com",
        "Telephone": "01234 555555",
        "Address": {
          "Line1": "1 Street",
          "Line2": "City",
          "Zipcode": "012345"
        },
        "Employment": [
          {
            "EmployerName": "AAA Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1980-04-01",
            "EndDate": "1990-11-01"
          },
          {
            "EmployerName": "ABC Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1990-12-01",
            "EndDate": "1995-10-01"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PaymentInformation": [
        {
          "Type": "A",
          "Amount": 2000,
          "Increased": true
        },
        {
          "Type": "B",
          "Amount": 1000,
          "Increased": false
        }
      ],
      "ExtraInfo": [
        {
          "Info": "ABC",
          "Comments": [
            "A", "B", "C"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Info": "EFG",
          "Comments": [
            "E", "F", "G"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "2024-04-18T12:30:00Z",
      "Information": {
        "Name": "Jane",
        "Reference": "CZE0866",
        "Email": "test1@test.com",
        "Telephone": "01234 12345",
        "Address": {
          "Line1": "12 Street",
          "Line2": "City",
          "Zipcode": "0123450"
        },
        "Employment": [
          {
            "EmployerName": "CZE Ltd",
            "StartDate": "1960-04-01",
            "EndDate": "1980-11-01"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PaymentInformation": [
        {
          "Type": "A",
          "Amount": 3000,
          "Increased": true
        }
      ],
      "ExtraInfo": [
        {
          "Info": "XYZ",
          "Comments": [
            "X", "Y", "Z"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "2024-04-18T12:30:00Z",
      "Information": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Reference": "ZYZ0866",
        "Email": "test2@test.com",
        "Telephone": "01234 121121",
        "Address": {
          "Line1": "123 Street",
          "Line2": "City",
          "Zipcode": "01234567"
        },
        "Employment": [
          {
            "EmployerName": "ABC Ltd",
            "StartDate": "2000-04-01",
            "EndDate": "2001-11-01"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PaymentInformation": [
        {
          "Unavailable": "TBC"
        }
      ],
      "ExtraInfo": [
        {
          "Unavailable": "TBC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I used same solution from this question. It's on .NET 8 and ChoETL package. I have all POCO class mapped and decorated, also the convert classes. The Employment array was ok but couldn't make PaymentInformation or ExtraInfo working. Either empty or null reference exception. This is different than the linked question. If PaymentInformation or ExtraInfo are at same level of Employment, i.e. inside Information that solution works; but they are not, they are outside Information, although I mapped POCO accordingly, it didn't work.
I am expecting following csv:
Date,Name,Reference,Email,Telephone,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,Zipcode,EmployerName,EmplymentStartDate,EmplymentStartEndDate,EmployerName1,EmplymentStartDate1,EmplymentStartEndDate1,PaymentType,PaymentAmout,PaymentIncreased,PaymentType1,PaymentAmout1,PaymentIncreased1,ExtraInfo,Comments,ExtraInfo1,Comments1
2024-04-18 12:30:00,Joe,AAA0866,test@test.com,01234 555555,1 Street,City,012345,AAA Ltd,1980-04-01,1990-11-01,ABC Ltd,1990-12-01,1996-10-01,A,2000,true,B,1000,false,ABC,A+B+C,EFG,E+F+G
2024-04-18 12:30:00,Jane,CZE0866,test1@test.com,01234 12345,12 Street,City,0123450,CZE Ltd,1960-04-01,1980-11-01,,,,A,3000,true,,,,XYZ,X+Y+Z,,
2024-04-18 12:30:00,John,ZYZ0866,test2@test.com,01234 121121,123 Street,City,01234567,ABC Ltd,2000-04-01,2001-11-01,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Update:
After using JObject and JArray from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to move the array around, I resolve the issue.

You have linked to what seems to be an exact duplicate question which has an accepted answer. It's unclear how this question differs and exactly how the other answer does not solve your problem or how you are having trouble implementing the answer.

Unlike Employment inside Information, it works from the solution in that linked question, butPaymentInformation and ExtraInfo are outside Information, which I couldn't make them work and don't understand why.
